# how to authenticate the proxy in urlsession?

Tags: authentication, proxy, swift3, nsurlcredential, urlsession

Hi I'm trying to add proxy with credentials to my App but whenever I'm tried, 
I got following (In Xcode) console warning:

```
*** WARNING: CFMachPortSetInvalidationCallBack() called on a CFMachPort with a Mach port (0x900b) which does not have any send rights.  This is not going to work.  Callback function: 0x181bcf524
```

Also Got Alert with following description

```
Authentication for HTTP proxy
MyProxyHost
MyProxyPort
```

When I cancel the popup then it's calling following method

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void)
```

I debug the challenge in **Xcode console** and got following debugDescription:

```
po challenge.protectionSpace.debugDescription
"<NSURLProtectionSpace: 0x12f685ad0>: Host: MyProxyHost, Server:http, Auth-Scheme:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic, Realm:(null), Port: MyProxyPort, Proxy:YES, Proxy-Type:http"
```

My Question is how to deal with proxy authentication ?

My code:

```
func getURLCredential() -> URLCredential {

        let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
        return credential
    }
```

From below dictionary, I'm able to hit the proxy but unable to authenticate the proxy.

```
// Create an NSURLSessionConfiguration that uses the proxy
    let proxyDict: [AnyHashable: Any]? = [(kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPEnable as AnyHashable): Int(1), (kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPProxy as AnyHashable): proxyServerString, (kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPPort as AnyHashable): proxyPortNumber, (kCFProxyUsernameKey as AnyHashable): userNameKey, (kCFProxyPasswordKey as AnyHashable): password]
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyDict
```

I tried several below methods but fail:

```
let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", user, password)
        let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()// base64EncodedData(options: [])
configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : base64LoginString]
```

Another way:

```
let protectionSpace:URLProtectionSpace = URLProtectionSpace(host: proxyHost, port: proxyPort, protocol: "http", realm: nil, authenticationMethod: NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic)
        let credentialStorage = URLCredentialStorage.shared//.allCredentials

        credentialStorage.set(getURLCredential(), for: protectionSpace)
        configuration.urlCredentialStorage = credentialStorage
```

ANOTHER WAY:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        print("Challenge:")

        guard challenge.previousFailureCount == 0 else {
            print("Previous Failure Count = \(challenge.previousFailureCount)")
            print("Cancelling Challenge\n")
            challenge.sender?.cancel(challenge)

            // Inform the user that the user name and password are incorrect
            completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
            return
        }
        print("Use Credential ....\n")

        completionHandler(.useCredential, self.getURLCredential())
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0
        {
            print("Alert Please check the credential")
            debugPrint("Alert Please check the credential")
            completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        }

        challenge.sender?.use(self.getURLCredential(), for: challenge)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, self.getURLCredential())
    }
```

unable to authenticate.

Please suggest me how to authenticate the proxy in swift 3?

Comment: Did u ever found answer for this? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
URLSessionConfiguration
```

need additional headers.

```
let configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Proxy-Authorization":  Request.authorizationHeader(user: "user", password: "password") ]
```

Comment: Hi, if I set the `connectionProxyDictionary` which is part of `NSURLSessionConfiguration`... do you know if it can set this header ("Proxy-Authorization") automatically ? thanks

Comment: I don't know @Zohar81 . I built a Singleton of  `URLSessionConfiguration` and reuse it every time I need proxy autorization.

Answer (score 1):

Each of your approaches has a different bug:

- The `Authorization` header is for authenticating yourself to the remote server, not the proxy.  You would want to set the `Proxy-Authorization` header.
- The kCFProxy* keys you used are not valid in a proxy dictionary (and this is why using a dictionary as a data structure is a fundamentally bad design, BTW, for folks designing future APIs).  Those keys are used solely when configuring a `CF(Read|Write)Stream`.  You want `kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost` and friends.  For a valid proxy dictionary example, see [this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101582/how-to-programmatically-add-a-proxy-to-an-nsurlsession).
- You implemented a session-level delegate method for handling authentication challenges.  Unfortunately, that method does not get called for proxy authentication.  Only the task-level delegate method (`URLSession:task:...`) gets called for proxy authentication.