# AFNetworking Setting UserName and password for proxy

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, alamofire, nsurlsession

I want to set proxy with Username and password for AFNetworking.
Below Is my code:

```
proxyDict = @{
@"HTTPEnable"  : [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                  (NSString *)kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPProxy  : proxyHost,
                  (NSString *)kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPPort  : proxyPortFormted,
                  };

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    sessionConfiguration.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyDict;

 NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[mutableRequest addValue:@"header Name" forHTTPHeaderField:@"header Value"];
```

After Adding this I am getting:

> "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"

For this problem. I add this line.

```
 manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes                           setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
```

After Adding the above line. I am getting this error.

> "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.,

But its working correctly

```
 curl --proxy proxyIP:proxyPort -U headerName:headerPassword.
```

Please help

Comment: check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101582/how-to-programmatically-add-a-proxy-to-an-nsurlsession

Comment: Hi Lalit Kumar I have check with this, but it is not working again. Any other solution from your side.                                                                         (NSString *)kCFProxyUsernameKey : userName,
(NSString *)kCFProxyPasswordKey : passwrod,

Comment: manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"]; please check this is added or not

Comment: Hi I have check this previously I checked again Its the same problem. "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"

Comment: Check this all self.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];

Comment: After adding that. I am getting this error now. "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set"